# External HDD not showing in explorer, only have "Delete Volume" in Disk Management

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive, disk-management

my external hard disk is not showing up in Explorer. In Disk Management, all of the options are grayed out except for "Delete Volume".

I tried right-clicking on the Disk and selecting "Convert to Dynamic Disk", but it returned with error message "The operation is not supported by the object".

Is there anything I can do to access it so I can backup my data?

[image: External HDD is Disk 1]

Comment: so there is no data on the external drive?

Comment: @CarlB: There is. I tried running Zero Assumption Recovery on it and it does found some data. But the structure is incomplete hence why I prefer to be able to access the HDD the normal way and backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), I discovered that my external HDD had actually been converted to Linux file system. Such a shame that even Windows 8, Disk Management can't at least tell if the hard disk is using a file system created in Mac or Linux.

I managed to back up all of my documents on Windows itself, using [DiskInternals Linux](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/).